# Get difference of two numbers in two different rows/columns with sqlite / php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a SQLite Database with a table called "events", it has the following structure:

```
rowid       ID                  startTimestamp   endTimestamp
1           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   1000             1010
2           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   1100             1030
3           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   1090             1110   
4           00:50:c2:63:10:1a   1210             1310
.
.
.
```

It's no problem to calculate the average time between startTimestamp and endTimestamp:

```
SELECT ID, avg(endTimestamp - startTimestamp) AS duration FROM events WHERE senderID ="00:50:c2:63:10:1a"
```

But now i want to have the average differences between the endTime and the startTime between one row and the following row, that means for my example:

1100-1010 = 90

1090-1030 = 60

1210-1110 = 100

---

Sum of differences = 90 + 60 + 100 = 250

Average Difference = 250 / 3 = 83,33

Is there a way to do this with an SQL Query? Or should is it necessary to write a piece of code in PHP?

Comment: How can the `endTime` be before the `startTime` (as it is in `rowid=2`)?

Comment: @ypercube at first impression I thought it would want to go by 60 minutes.. but not really the case here either.. When `endtime` before `starttime` I juset used `ABS`.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    id,
    ( MAX(endtimestamp) - MIN(startTimestamp)
    - SUM(endtimestamp-startTimestamp)
    ) / (COUNT(*)-1) AS averageDifference
FROM
    events
GROUP BY
    id ;
```

Tested at SQL-Fiddle: **[test-1](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66cbe/4)** (thanks to @bonCodigo for that)

---

Since the `MIN(endtimestamp)` may not be the one with lowest `rowid`, the above query needs a **correction**:

```
SELECT
    id,
    ( ( SELECT endtimestamp FROM events AS ee 
        WHERE ee.id = e.id ORDER BY rowid ASC LIMIT 1 )
    - ( SELECT startTimestamp FROM events AS ee
        WHERE ee.id = e.id ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1 )
    - SUM(endtimestamp-startTimestamp)
    ) / (COUNT(*)-1) AS averageDifference
FROM
    events AS e
GROUP BY
    id ;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great! Is there the possibility to calculate the variance or the standard deviation of the average difference grouped by id ?

Comment: You mean if you have 3 IDs with averageDifferences 83.3 , 90 and 120, calculate the standard deviation of these 3 values?

Comment: @ypercube `+1` for getting OP's request right :) What really is the difference here from my query? Taking MIN, MAX? Looks same as my fiddle though ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo: Yes, you didn't take into account the first StartTime and the last Endtime. And you used `COUNT(*)` while mine has `COUNT(*)-1`. If there are 4 rows, the differences are 3.

Comment: But in OP's example `sum of differences = 90 + 60 + 100 = 250

Average Difference = 250 / 3 = 83,33` he doesn't say so... he is showing 3 times, getting sum of 3, and dividing by 3..

Comment: @bonCodigo: But these 3 values come from 4 rows of the table (rowid=1,2,3,4)

Comment: Oh the Zig, Zag.. 2nd row start_time - 1st row end_time ;) got it. Only I wish that I have noticed that sigh :D at least fiddle was helpful to you.

Comment: @ypercube: No, i mean you have 90, 60, 100 as differences for 00:50:c2:63:10:1a in your SQLFiddle. I will have a large amount of these differences and indicators like the standard deviation / variance are important for me. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,( SUM(duration) / COUNT(*) ) duration
FROM (SELECT ID, (endTimestamp - startTimestamp) AS duration 
      FROM events WHERE senderID ="00:50:c2:63:10:1a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: not sure if you want to use `abs` but adjust it accordingly. In my sample I have only used your first few rows. But if you want to use different data then you may add the proper `id` values to the `where condition`:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffc18/1)

```
select id, 
sum(abs(endtimestamp - starttimestamp))/Count(*) 
as span from table1
where id = '00:50:c2:63:10:1a'
group by id
;
```

Results for all ID in the sample table:

```
|                ID | SPAN |
----------------------------
| 00:50:c2:63:10:1a |   50 |
| 00:50:c2:63:10:2a |  100 |
```